# Reverse engineering from mysql to mongodb_most suitable method

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

In mysql we writes,

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student , Course
WHERE Student.course_id = Course.id 
AND Course.name = "English"
```

we can do the same thing in mongodb as(in PHP)

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection1 = new MongoCollection($db, 'Course');
$cursor = $collection1->find(array("name"=>"English"));

$collection2 = new MongoCollection($db, 'Student');


foreach($cursor as $res) {
    $cursor = $collection2->find(array("course_id"=>array($in=>$res['id'])));
    //do something with the result
}
```

Or there is another method with prejoin or embedded collections as follow.

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection1 = new MongoCollection($db, 'Student');
$cursor = $collection1->find(array("name"=>"Course.English"));

//do something with result
```

embedded as follow

```
Student=>array(

id=>...,

Course=>[]

)
```

1).I'm confused with what is the best solution.
2).What is the best when two collection is used separately many times also in a project.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do ... seems like maybe a join?

Comment: Yeah, But there are no concept called join in mongodb. so we have to do like that.

Comment: Yes, there's no joins. However, it's still not clear what you're trying to do. Often the `$in` operator is used to grab batches of related documents from a secondary collection.

Comment: Yeah it's my mistake. I edited that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since two collections are used frequently, embedding two collection is cause that operations slower. (accessing the data in collections separately.) So in here following code can be used.

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection1 = new MongoCollection($db, 'Course');
$cursor = $collection1->find(array("name"=>"English"));

$collection2 = new MongoCollection($db, 'Student');


foreach($cursor as $res) {

    $cursor = $collection2->find(array("course_id"=>array($in=>$res['id'])));
    //do something with the result
}

in here if you need to retrive data from collection2,

$resArr = array();
foreach($cursor as $res) {

array_push($resArr ,$res['id']);

}

  $cursor2 = $collection2->find(array("course_id"=>array($in=>$resArr)));


foreach($cursor2 as $res2) {

    //do something with the result
}
```